# Mysql how to update field with commas etc

Tags: mysql

I have the following table that I want to update in mysql:

```
mysql> select name,value from variable where value like '%ab@example.com%';
+----------------------+-----------------------------------+
| name                 | value                             |
+----------------------+-----------------------------------+
| update_notify_emails | a:1:{i:0;s:15:"ab@example.com";} |
+----------------------+-----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I want to change the email address only i.e. ab@example.com to de@example2.com in the table above so  it will look like ---->>>      **a:1:{i:0;s:15:"de@example2.com";}**

I have tried the following sql but it does not update like I have done previously with more simpler data - nothing happens:

```
update `variable` set `name` = replace(name, 'a:1:{i:0;s:15:"ab@example.com";}','a:1:{i:0;s:15:"de@example2.com";}');
```

I'm assuming the semi-colons etc are causing a problem ?  Can they be escaped or is there a better way to update this ?

Thanks

Comment: Just realised I had should have been changing "value" instead of "name" !!! .....working now after changing the values ...

Comment: with this structure, then what is the use of mysql DBMS !!?

Comment: Its a drupal database table - I did not create it !